# When initialising new objects is triggering new templates in meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I was building a page that needs to create a matrix where the number or rows and columns are reactive (which can be changed by the user clicking "add rows", etc..)

I used a function which prepares the contents for each cell, client side:

```
function prepareCells(rows, columns){
    let matrixContent = {};
    ...logics here...
    return matrixContent;
}
```

In the clients there was also the following helper:

```
Template.matrix.helpers({

matrixContents(){
    const instance = Template.instance();
    let rows = instance.state.get("rows");
    let columns = instance.state.get("columns");    
    return prepareCells(rows, columns);
},
```

Finally in the html Blaze page there is something like:

```
{{#each row in matrixContents.rows}}
     {{#each row.cell}}
          {{> cellcontent}}
     {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Whenever the reactive variables changes, the helper is re-run.. but the onCreated function of the "cellContent" template is not! For instance if you add a row, the onCreated is run only n times (where n is the current number of columns), whereas the function "prepareCells" always return a fresh object. Inside the onCreated there was some relevant logic which must be executed to initialise properly reactive variables of the cellcontent.

What is the pattern used by Meteor to decide when to create or not new templates? I've found a workaround where the helpers of cellcontent (the inner template) use currentData:

```
Template.cellcontent.helpers({
    getFoo(){
         let data = Template.currentData();
         ...logic with the "real" data inside the cellcontent
    }
```

Because helpers of cellcontent relying on a reactiveDict would find unexpected values, since the reactiveDict was initiated onCreated, which was not always run, e.g.:

```
Template.cellcontent.helpers({
    getFoo(){
         let template = Template.instance();
         instance.state =....you get unexpected data here

    }
```

Is there a reference on this behaviour?

Comment: You need to place reactive based logic on `onCreated` in autorun - http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-autorun

Comment: Thanks, the reference helped me understand a bit better the engine, if you post it I'll check it as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to re-run your `onCreated` function you need a) to add an `autorun` b) bind it to a reactive source, so the source triggers the autorun and finally c) pass in some data in order to trigger the autorun.

Given your example above this could look like the following:

```js
Template.cellcontent.onCreated(function cellContentOnCreated() {

  const instance = this;
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict(); // to save the processed data

  // a - autorun this instance on changing incoming data
  instance.autorun(function autorun() {

    // b - autobind to a reactive data source
    // because Template.currentData() is in a reactive context
    // autorun will automatically re-run if it changes
    const data = Template.currentData();
    const processedData = //... process your incoming data
    instance.state.set('processedData', processedData);
  });

});

Template.cellcontent.helpers({
  getFoo(){
    return Template.instance().state.get('processedData');
  }
});
```

In order to achieve c) you need to pass in some data to your cell content template:

```
{{#each row in matrixContents.rows}}
     {{#each row.cell}}
          {{> cellcontent data=this}}
     {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Note, that `this` represents the current element in the each block and requires `row.cell` to be an array of cell content elements. If this is not the case, you may review this structure and reorganize it, so that cell content data is passed to the `cellcontent` template.